# How to detect when a new SATA drive is inserted using Java under Linux?

Tags: java, linux, sata

I am currently working on a project where I need to bulk import data into a Hadoop cluster. The data that needs to be imported into Hadoop resides on SATA disks. The data that needs to be imported are Encase forensics disks image (E01). I created an application that extract files from these images and import those files into Hadoop, this works fine but I need to start the process by hand.

I want to automate the process by hot-swapping the SATA drives and automatically start the extract process. I wrote my program in Java and it needs to be that way due to some external libraries I use to analyse the images. I searched the internet for a solution where Java is used to detect newly inserted drives but all I found where libraries that can detect usb drive or used udev rules to kick start the a process (I could use that but prefer a Java solution)

Does anyone know if something like what I have described exists? Or does anyone can point me into the right direction? It would be much appreciated!

Almost forgot...I use ubuntu 12.04 Server Edition as my operating system.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert by any means, but the existence of such a mechanism seems very doubtful to me. You'd practically need a Java API to udev, or the kernel itself. Of course, I guess you could just as well do that with JNI...

Comment: I will have in mind: polling the mount point, JNotify or I think the new Java7 file IO may help.

Comment: Is the entire server under your control, or are you needing to be able to install this application on someone else's machine?

Answer (score 5):

[udisks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) is a D-Bus API that provides information (including notifications) on media insertion and removal, and you could subscribe to the notifications using [dbus-java](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/).

Alternatively, you could have your Java application listen on a `localhost` socket and write a `udev` rule that sent the appropriate event information over the socket.

Comment: The server is fully under my control. I had a quick look at dbus-java and it seems to be something I could use..tnx!